# Check for Airplane mode while data roaming is enabled with Apple's Reachability Class

Tags: ios, reachability, airplane-mode

The below snippet is used to check the network availability in an application using Apple's Reachability class.

```
- (BOOL) networkAvailable{
return connectivityStatus != NotReachable && ![delegate isForcedOutOfCoverage];}
```

isForcedOutOfCoverage is an application method that always returns the correct value.

The problem is that NotReachable value is 'No' when the device is in data roaming ON mode while in Airplane mode; which means that network is available (roaming is enabled before comes to Airplane mode).

Anyone has similar experience in Apple's Reachability class with data roaming and Airplane mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another question would be, how data roaming is identified in iOS using Reachability Module by Apple?